# Typo3 website - Strange characters concatenated to my URLs

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5

I have a Typo3 website version 4.5. I just realized that when I click on the links in my website sometimes strange characters are appended to the URL of that webpage in the browser.

The website has two languages: Spanish and English. An example of correct URL is:

> In Spanish -> http://mysite/index.php?id=10
>
> In English -> http://mysite/index.php?id=10&L=2

But sometimes I get something like this:

> In Spanish -> http://mysite/index.php?id=10&L=txtnpoyrf or
>   http://mysite/index.php?id=10&L=2%20\\%27
>
> In English -> http://mysite/index.php?id=10%20\\%27&L=2

The content is showed correctly and if I navigate just in English URLs are displayed correctly.  Why could this be happening? How could I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are those characters already in the pages source code, or do they appear later (and thus are added by js or so)? What is the value of the `config.linkVars` and `page.config.linkVars` TypoScript settings? Assuming the used page object is name `page`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on some sites, where some spambots(?) tried to inject spamlinks into the site by using the `L` parameter.

When TYPO3 is configured to have the parameter `L`as variable for your language UIDs, then it by default accepts anything (also strings) as valid arguments. TYPO3 then just adds the given argument for the `L` parameter to the output and also caches all entries in the local cache.

To avoid this, you can force TYPO3 to only accept integers as valid `L` arguments.

```
config.linkVars = L(int)
```

Make sure you clean the TYPO3 cache after you added the settings described above.